# Eevee render lighting issue

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, lighting

been trying to do some product animation, and my issue is that my render is showing incorrect lighting that isn't similar to my view port, even with disabling the lights in renders, they're still showing up when I render, even when disabling all the lights in the scene I found out that the issue still persists, and just the phone body alone shows up with this side lighting issue.

pictures are for my view port and the other is with lighting disabled[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My issue is I'm trying to figure out why the bottom picture is my render result even when I disable all lighting in the scene, and why my render with lights enabled is different from my view port render.

Comment: how did you "disable" the lighting? did you use the "eye" icon or the "camera" icon?

Comment: are you sure that you've disabled the lights for render? Check your Outliner settings? If you still don't find, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I've disabled using the camera icon "Disable in Renders".

Comment: @moonboots here is the file https://pasteall.org/blend/0907ea73009d4bdf818b77909659e2a5

Answer (score 0):

The collection called *Collection* is disabled for preview but it is enabled for render, so just disable it for render as well:

[image]

Also you have loaded a strip in the Video Sequencer, in that case maybe you should disable the *Output > Post-Processing > Sequencer* option?